# UIWebView linking to a same-page anchor not resetting scroll on [webview goBack]

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I'm loading a local file from the bundle into UIWebView using loadRequest.  The file has a link to an anchor in the same file.  Clicking on the link scrolls properly to the anchor.  However, if [webView goBack] is called, the file reloads and sets the scroll offset to 0 - not where the scroll was before.

I am able to fix it in iOS 8 by looking for a navigationType of UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked and saving the scroll offset, then restoring it after the [webview goBack].  However, in iOS 7, shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never called again if the same link is selected.

Anybody have a better solution?